# Setting Start and End dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a simple query that needs to pull in all employees that were hired in the past 10 days, up until end of day yesterday at 11:59, excluding the current date, using Start & End date variables.

I know there's MANY ways of setting this date range.
What is the most efficient SQL server expression that can give you the start and end dates for the past 10 days, excluding the current date?

```
    DECLARE @StartDate = ???
    DECLARE @EndDate = ???

    SELECT @StartDate, @EndDate
```

Desired outcome:

```
    2020-04-02 00:00:00.000, 2020-04-11 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: Given you know many ways, try them out and inspect the execution plan to find out which performs the best.

Comment: your desired outcome is probably wrong anyway. You should likely be using `>=` and `<` with whole dates, not inclusive until `23:59:59.000`

Answer (score 3):

The :59 schemes are a bad idea.  Comparisons should be less than the (start of) next day in order to include the full previous day.

```
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,-10,CAST(getdate() AS DATE)), @EndDate = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

However if you still want it:

```
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,-10,CAST(getdate() AS DATE)), @EndDate = DATEADD(ss,-1,CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Code Works fine for your Case:

```
SELECT 

@Start=CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-10 AS DATE) AS DATETIME),
@End=CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE),' 23:59:59.000') ---
```